# Summarize producing errors in Azure ML

Tags: r, azure

I'm having trouble finding the max value for a group. I've tried several different options (summarise, tapply) and always get the "replacement has x rows, data has y" error. I've looked into the error, but can't seem to find a solution.

```html
  # Extracting the max of Cal_Dly_Oil over that time:
  dataset1$Max_Dly_Oil <- ""
  dataset1 %>% group_by(Well_ID)
  dataset1$Max_Dly_Oil <- summarise(max(dataset1$Cal_Dly_Oil))
```

Can someone spot the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue stems from the fact that R and dplyr are out of date in Azure ML.